# External users and standard profiles

Tags: profile, partner-communities, spring14, contracts

In the Spring 14 release notes are the following two points:

"Object permissions for contracts have been added to standard profiles. If your organization uses contracts and Communities, note that external users assigned to standard profiles may have access to your organization’s contracts." From: http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_networks_contracts.htm

"Once orders are enabled, standard profiles automatically include all object permissions for orders... If your external users are assigned to a standard profile and these object permissions aren’t appropriate for them, consider creating custom profiles that don’t include these object permissions." From: http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_networks_orders.htm

I'd really like to expose Contracts in a Partner Community - until now they've not been exposed, there are no CRED options on the profile. The above makes me think this is changing, but from having a look in a pre-release org, this doesn't seem to be the case.

So, now to the relatively simple question: how can an external user be assigned to a standard profile, as per the quotes above? Note that the Contracts page lists out the standard profiles affected, so this doesn't seem to apply to all standard (i.e. including Partner Community) profiles. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I can't quite grasp it!